# Use a table of data to plot a region instead of RegionPlot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, regions

I have an equation that I want to plot as a region plot but it takes a long time to plot and in the future, I will need to replot it multiple times so is it possible to replot a region plot from a table of data?

An example of a simpler equation and code to extract the data points is

```
plot = RegionPlot[x^2 + y^3 < 2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]

dataPts = DeleteDuplicates@Flatten[Cases[Normal[plot], Polygon[x_] :> x, Infinity], 1];
```

This gives a {601,2} table of coordinates

[image: Coordinates of region plot]

which make up the region plot below.

[image: RegionPlot]

Can I recreate the region plot from a table of data?

Comment: This is not really an answer to your _question_, but a suggestion to what you want to achieve: Why don't you plot the region _once_, and then use ``Show`` to combine it with (I presume) other plots? ``reg = RegionPlot[...]; Show[reg, Plot[...]]; Show[reg, Plot[...]];``

Comment: As for the real question: take a look at [``NonConvexHullMesh``](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/NonConvexHullMesh).

Comment: @Domen The problem is that I might have to update the plot style retrospectively and then combine with other region plots using Show as you have suggested. As for using NonConvexHullMesh I don't see how this can be used to recreate a region plot when given a table of data but maybe I've misunderstood something.

Answer (score 2):

As Domen mentioned, first fetch the "NonConvexHullMesh" function:

```
nchm= ResourceFunction["NonConvexHullMesh"]
```

Then create your data points:

```
plot = RegionPlot[x^2 + y^3 < 2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
dataPts = DeleteDuplicates@Flatten[Cases[Normal[plot], Polygon[x_] :> x, Infinity], 1];
```

Now apply the function to the data points:

```
newregion = nchm[dataPts, 0.7];
```

Finally compare the original region and the new region:

```
Region[newregion, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {-2, 2}, PlotLabel -> "New Region"]
plot
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! For the sensitivity option for NonConvexHullMesh is there a sure-fire setting choice of value for getting as close to the original region plot as possible or do you try various values and select the value which gives the best agreement?

Comment: The larger the  sensitivity value,  the more the region will become convex. You have to try for an optimal value.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach is to extract the coordinates of `Line` primitives (instead of  `Polygon` coordinates):

```
plot = RegionPlot[x^2 + y^3 < 2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, ImageSize -> 400];

boundaryCoords = Cases[Normal @ plot, Line[x_] :> x, All];

lines = Line /@ boundaryCoords;

graphicsBoundary = Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[1.6], ColorData[97]@1, lines}, 
  Options[plot]];
```

If the region does not have any holes, we can simply wrap `boundaryCoords` with `Polygon` to reproduce the union of polygons in original `RegionPlot` output:

```
polygons = Polygon /@ boundaryCoords;

graphicsRegion = Graphics[{EdgeForm[{AbsoluteThickness[1.6], ColorData[97]@1}], 
    FaceForm[Opacity[.3]], ColorData[97]@1, polygons}, Options[plot]];

Row[{Show[plot, PlotLabel -> Style["plot", 24]], 
  Show[graphicsBoundary, PlotLabel -> Style["graphicsBoundary", 24]], 
  Show[graphicsRegion, PlotLabel -> Style["graphicsRegion", 24]]}]
```

[image]

If the region has holes as in

```
plot = RegionPlot[ x^2 + y^3 < 2 && (1/4 <= (x + 1)^2 + (y + 1)^2 && 
      1/4 <= (x - 1)^2 + (y + 1)^2) || 
   0 <= (x + 1)^2 + (y + 1)^2 <= 1/16 || 0 <= (x - 1)^2 + (y + 1)^2 <= 1/16,
   {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},  ImageSize -> 400]
```

this approach gives:

[image]

So we need additional processing of `lines` to get the desired primitives. One possible approach is to group `lines` by region inclusion (using [`RegionWithin`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionWithin.html) + [`RelationGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RelationGraph.html) + [`WeaklyConnectedComponents`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeaklyConnectedComponents.html)) and construct [`FilledCurve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FilledCurve.html)s for each group of lines:

```
filledcurves = ReplaceAll[l : {__Line} :> FilledCurve[List /@ l]] @
    WeaklyConnectedComponents @
       RelationGraph[RegionWithin[Polygon @@ #, Polygon @@ #2] &, lines];

graphicsRegion = Graphics[{EdgeForm[{AbsoluteThickness[1.6], ColorData[97]@1}], 
    FaceForm[Opacity[.3]], ColorData[97]@1, filledcurves}, 
   Options[plot]];

Row[{Show[plot, PlotLabel -> Style["plot", 24]], 
  Show[graphicsBoundary, PlotLabel -> Style["graphicsBoundary", 24]], 
  Show[graphicsRegion, PlotLabel -> Style["graphicsRegion", 24]]}, 
 Spacer[20]]
```

[image]

A more complicated example:

```
SeedRandom[1]
plot = RegionPlot[Evaluate[1 <= Sum[Sin[RandomReal[6, 2].{x, y}], {5}] <= 3], 
   {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, PlotPoints -> 60, ImageSize -> 400];

boundaryCoords = Cases[Normal@plot, Line[x_] :> x, All];

lines = Line /@ boundaryCoords;

graphicsBoundary = Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[1.6], ColorData[97]@1, lines}, 
   Options[plot]];

filledcurves = ReplaceAll[l : {__Line} :> FilledCurve[List /@ l]] @
   WeaklyConnectedComponents @
       RelationGraph[RegionWithin[Polygon @@ #, Polygon @@ #2] &, lines];


graphicsRegion = Graphics[{EdgeForm[{AbsoluteThickness[1.6], ColorData[97]@1}], 
    FaceForm[Opacity[.3]], ColorData[97]@1, filledcurves}, 
   Options[plot]];

Row[{Show[plot, PlotLabel -> Style["plot", 24]], 
  Show[graphicsBoundary, PlotLabel -> Style["graphicsBoundary", 24]], 
  Show[graphicsRegion, PlotLabel -> Style["graphicsRegion", 24]]}, 
 Spacer[20]]
```

[image]